# Which set is this part 6082 from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Which set this is from, part number is 6082 or 60052.
[image: part 6082]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [Rock Panel 4 x 10 x 6 Rectangular (BURP) with Marbled Dark Green Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6082pb01) and it has been included in [three sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6082pb01&in=S).

Comment: thanks for answering

Answer (score 3):

The set is 7036-1 one of the three sets containing the part.

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7036